# Can the tag "lein" become a synonym of "leiningen"?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

The [lein](/questions/tagged/lein) tag should be a synonym for the [leiningen](/questions/tagged/leiningen) tag. (Where [leiningen](/questions/tagged/leiningen) is the parent.)

[Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) is the proper name, but it is generally abbreviated as "lein".

Comment: It looks like someone created it. Thanks!